# Try Catch Continue

Tags: c#, try-catch

I would like to ask if there's a way for me to put an if condition inside my try block and when it the condition returns true it will proceed to the next line of my try condition?

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
private void sendReminderEmail_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (editedCustomerRequest.OwnerID == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Hashtable xsltValues = new Hashtable();

            xsltValues.Add("fso:LicenseKeyRequest", request);
            string xsltTemplateFile = string.Format("{0}{1}", workflowProperties.WebUrl, _configItems[_lkrAdminReminderEmailTemplateUrl]);                
            Email email = new Email(xsltTemplateFile, xsltValues);
         }
```

Comment: I don't get the question... what exactly do you mean by 'the next line of my try condition'?

Comment: Can you elaborate your questions ? Which next line ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no

> Try condition

However if you are looking for something like `continue` or `break` which you can use in loops, there is no such keyword for try blocks. This is because `try` blocks are simply used for exception catching or if you want to add `finally` code regardless of something returning. `try` blocks are not conditional. However this can be accomplished by structuring your loops/conditional blocks in the proper way.

```
try
{
    if (editedCustomerRequest.OwnerID != null)
    {
        Hashtable xsltValues = new Hashtable();

        xsltValues.Add("fso:LicenseKeyRequest", request);
        string xsltTemplateFile = string.Format("{0}{1}", workflowProperties.WebUrl, _configItems[_lkrAdminReminderEmailTemplateUrl]);
        Email email = new Email(xsltTemplateFile, xsltValues);
    }
}
```

You could use `goto` but I do not recommend it. Resorting to `goto` means you're doing something wrong and should be restructuring your program instead. I just wanted you to know that it technically is an option. Note: `goto` only work if there is code after them. But again.... you shouldn't use this.

```
try
{
    if (editedCustomerRequest.OwnerID == null)
    {
        goto exitTry;
    }

    Hashtable xsltValues = new Hashtable();

    xsltValues.Add("fso:LicenseKeyRequest", request);
    string xsltTemplateFile = string.Format("{0}{1}", workflowProperties.WebUrl, _configItems[_lkrAdminReminderEmailTemplateUrl]);                
    Email email = new Email(xsltTemplateFile, xsltValues);
 }
 catch(){}
 exitTry:
```

Answer (score 0):

Just invert the if-clause:

```
if (editedCustomerRequest.OwnerID != null)
{
    // rest of your code
}
```

That's, what I understand by your question. I prefer the way you have it now, but that's opinion-based.

Answer (score -1):

When you use a try/catch statement it analyzes all the code you put in the try statement. If you're looking for a way to see where the try statement fails I would recommend you simply debug your code. You can also make more than one try catch within a try statement.

Comment: Where does a try/catch analyze something? Exceptions thrown in the try block will be catched in any of the defined catch blocks.

Comment: Whatever you put in the try block gets analyzed and if it fails it goes to the catch block. Why exactly was my comment downvoted? Was it because I said analyzed instead of exception was thrown? Because I used wrong English word...